# Use python to split a list of values into two lists when negative value occurs when looping

Tags: python, list, loops, split

Let's say I have a list of floats. I was wondering how I would loop through the list and whenever a negative value occurs, to split the list into two separate lists.

The initial set of values:
[0.1,
0.5,
3.2,
8.2,
0.0,
19.7,
0.0,
-0.8,
-12.0,
-8.2,
-2.5,
-6.9,
-1.3,
0.0]

Example result I am looking for:

listA = [0.1, 0.5, 3.2, 8.2, 0.0, 19.7, 0.0]

listB = [-0.8, -12.0, -8.2, -2.5, -6.9, -1.3, 0.0]

The key here would be that the length of the list would vary, and the position at which the first negative value occurs is never the same.

So in short: wherever the first negative value occurs, split into two separate lists.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
-Cheers

Answer (score 5):

First, you may use [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to find the index of the first negative value:

```
neg = next((i for i, v in enumerate(values) if v < 0), -1)
```

Then, slice your list (assuming `neg != -1`):

```
listA, listB = values[:neg], values[neg:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is very simple, looping through your list, if the number is positive then add it to the first list, if the number is negative then turn the `saw_negative = True` and from now on append to the second list.

```
li = [0.1, 0.5, 3.2, 8.2, 0.0, 19.7, 0.0, -0.8, -12.0, -8.2, -2.5, -6.9, -1.3, 0.0]
first_li = []
second_li = []
saw_negative = False
for item in li:
    if item >= 0 and not saw_negative:
        first_li.append(item)
    elif item < 0 or saw_negative:
        saw_negative = True
        second_li.append(item)
print first_li
print second_li
```

**Output:**

```
[0.1, 0.5, 3.2, 8.2, 0.0, 19.7, 0.0]
[-0.8, -12.0, -8.2, -2.5, -6.9, -1.3, 0.0]
```

This is another approach, until the number is negative append the number to the first list, whenever the number is negative append the rest of the list to the second list and break the loop

```
li = [0.1, 0.5, 3.2, 8.2, 0.0, 19.7, 0.0, -0.8, -12.0, -8.2, -2.5, -6.9, 
-1.3, 0.0]
first_li = []
second_li = []
for index, item in enumerate(li):
    if item < 0:
        second_li = li[index:]
        break
    first_li.append(item)
print first_li
print second_li
```

**Output:**

```
[0.1, 0.5, 3.2, 8.2, 0.0, 19.7, 0.0]
[-0.8, -12.0, -8.2, -2.5, -6.9, -1.3, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in functional style using the [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) functions from the `itertools` standard library module:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

def split_at_first_negative(lst):
    """Split the list at the first occurrence of a negative value.

    >>> split_at_first_negative([1, 2, 3, -1, -5, -3, 5, -6, 1])
    ([1, 2, 3], [-1, -5, -3, 5, -6, 1])
    """
    groups = groupby(lst, lambda x: x >= 0)
    first = list(next(groups)[1])
    second = list(chain.from_iterable(g[1] for g in groups))
    return first, second
```